# pdf2json fail on passing a pdf from http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I'm trying to get information from PDF files on nodejs script.

I get this error when executing the program.

```
Error: stream must have data
at error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js:60:6), <anonymous>:193:7)
....
```

Here is the code:

```
http.get(url_Of_Pdf_File, function(res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        // Here body have the pdf content
        pdf2table.parse(body, function (err, rows, rowsdebug) { // <-- Conflict
            // Code fail executing the previous line
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            toMyFormat(rows, function(data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null," "));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I am not sure why the code does not work, because if I download the PDF file and then instead of getting with 'http.request' method I get the file with 'fs.readFile' method the code before works.

```
fs.readFile(pdf_file_path, function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    pdf2table.parse(buffer, function (err, rows, rowsdebug) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.timeEnd("Processing time");
        toMyFormat(rows, function(data){
            output(JSON.stringify(rows, null, " "));
        });
    });
});
```

My question is:

What is the difference between the content of 'body' and 'buffer' in two eamples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first example, `chunk` is buffer and you are converting it to utf8 string by adding it with empty body `''`. When you add buffer with string, it converts to utf8 and your original data is lost.

Try this:

```
var chunks = [];
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk)
});
res.on('end', function() {
    // Here body have the pdf content
    pdf2table.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks), function (err, rows, rowsdebug) {
       //...
    });
});
```